How do I use a Kubernetes Watcher to monitor namespace events in a cluster?
This is almost certainly a misuse/misread of the API on my end but was wondering if I could get some guidance on this:
This is my code snippet/attempt at creating a watcher to list all namespace events in my cluster:
Call v1NamespaceListCall = coreV1Api.listEventForAllNamespacesCall(BOOKMARK_ENABLED, null,
                null, null, null, NO_PRETTY_PRINT, null, null, WATCH_ENABLED, null);
                
Watch<V1Event> watch = Watch.createWatch(coreApi.getApiClient(), v1NamespaceListCall,
                new TypeToken<Response<V1Event>>(){}.getType());

I'm getting an API exception when creating a Watcher:Caused by: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: at io.kubernetes.client.util.Watch.createWatch(Watch.java:105) without much more detail in the stack trace. Am I creating a Watch of the incorrect type? I have a similar pod watcher that works fine but can't seem to be getting it to work for namespace events across a cluster.
I tried to read the documentation through and play around with different watchers

I'm not sure, but it might help if you [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace - formatted as a code block so as to keep the spacing, indentation and line breaks.

Yeah sorry, didn't realize Kubernetes Java API had it's own response body method to view the stack trace so figured it out after catching the exception and displaying the body.
If anybody ends up seeing this, it was an RBAC permission issue with my cluster and just had to add the correct permissions to view/list events.

Note that you can answer your own question. It may help other people having a similar issue who may come across your question when searching the Internet.

I didn't realize Kubernetes Java API had its own response body method to view the stack trace so figured it out after catching the exception and displaying the body. It ended up an RBAC permission issue with my cluster and just had to add the correct permissions via yaml to view/list events
